# How to keep two paths in sync in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a complex application and I am using Firebase for my backend data.

I have an object that is used in two different contexts, one for viewing by the user and one for the server to do batch processing. Something like this:

```
users: {
  USER_ID: {
     ...
     txns: {
       TXN_ID: {
          // data I need
       }
     }
 }
 ...
},
transactions: {
  TXN_ID: {
    USER_ID: {
      // data I need
    },
    USER_ID2: {
      // different data I need
    }
  }
}
```

In relational terms, txn_ids and user_ids are in a many-to-many relationship. So looking through the transactions node to find all the transactions that belong to a user is hard in FB and looking though all the users to find a transaction id is hard in FB. So I denormalize the data. I think this is correct.

But how do I keep them in sync?

I've been using MPUs, which is fine, but I'm worried about it being prone to bugs in the future.

I've considered writing a Firebase Cloud Function to keep them in sync, but I'm worried about that being more fragile than MPUs.

Advice?

Comment: What's MPU?  What's fragile about Cloud Functions, other than the fact that it's currently beta?

Comment: MPU = Multi-Path Updates.

Comment: Also, I'm worried about it being fragile. I'm not saying it is. Maybe the answer is that it isn't and that a cloud function *is* the best-practice way to do this.

Comment: This is a use case for Cloud Functions (keeping logic and organization in one place rather than depending on the client to do it right).

Comment: depending on the importance of the operation, you should use a batch write in a cloud function https endpoint.  cloud functions db triggers are nonatomic and aren't guaranteed to be reliable.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions